# Will Tensorflow Queue speed up data loading on a single CPU machine?

Tags: python, tensorflow, queue, gpu, cpu

I currently have some existing codes which work well on GPUs. I tried to run it on an Ubuntu machine with single GPU and a cluster server with multiple GPU. Both experiments are very fast.

However, when I tried to run it on my own laptop with one single CPU (no GPU), it becomes extremely low ... over 100X slower.

I understand it would be much slower when I don't have a GPU for training. But I really hope to understand if "Queue" is affected by such hardware platform difference.

Normally, we use CPUs to load data to GPUs through "queues", but it does not make any sense to play with one single CPU and use Tensorflow queues. Could anybody provide me with any guidance?

Comment: It's hard to identify the problem given the info provided, but general issues with the laptop include low CPU clock rate, CPU cores, HDD and occasionally low RAM speed. ... On my Ubuntu machine, GPU is about 20x faster than 4-core CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This suggestion may help you in the efficient usage of your CPU if it has multiple cores.

For getting a better performance, several parameters including OMP_NUM_THREADS, affinity domains, etc., need to be set according to the number of physical cores available.

You can try out the below optimization steps that helps in better utilization of your processor.

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=NUM_PARALLEL_EXEC_UNITS
export KMP_BLOCKTIME=30
export KMP_SETTINGS=1
export KMP_AFFINITY=granularity=fine,verbose,compact,1,0
```

NUM_PARALLEL_EXEC_UNITS is the number of physical cores.

The performance is found to be better when NUM_PARALLEL_EXEC_UNITS is equal to the number of physical cores. But this may vary. You can try different values to select the best.